# Visualizations are getting duplicated when using ipywidgets in Python jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, matplotlib, dropdown, ipywidgets

This is the code that I am using to output a drop down and a visualization. However with the drop down the visualization duplicates when I select a value.

def common_filtering(year):
output.clear_output()
plot_output.clear_output()

```
common_filter = Top_Team(year)

with output:
    display(common_filter)
    
with plot_output:
    plt.ioff
    test = common_filter.player_name.tolist()
    x = [10,35,30,30,35,65,65,65,100,95,95] 
    y = [40,10,30,50,70,20,40,60,40,60,20]
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    pitch = Pitch(pitch_type='statsbomb', orientation='vertical',
                  pitch_color='#22312b', line_color='#c7d5cc', figsize=(16, 20),
                  constrained_layout=True, tight_layout=False,axis = True,label = True)
    fig, ax = pitch.draw() 
    sc = pitch.scatter(x, y,
                          color ='red',edgecolors = 'black',
                            s=40000, ax=ax)

    for i,j,k in zip(x,y,test):
        
          pitch.annotate(k, (i,j),c='white', va='top', ha='center', size=16, weight='bold', ax=ax)

    fig.set_facecolor("#22312b")
    display(fig)
```

def dropdown_year_eventhandler(change):
common_filtering(change.new)

dropdown_year.observe(
dropdown_year_eventhandler, names='value')

display(dropdown_year) -- This is where the drop down is seen and underneath the duplicated visualizations

This is where essentially the output should be coming from and it is.
display(plot_output)
display(output)

Comment: I think you need to add parentheses to your `plt.ioff` see the explanation of ioff here: https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl/blob/master/examples/ipympl.ipynb

Comment: No that doesn't work either but I found the solution. You just need to close all visualizations that are being displayed and call it to display explicitly only. So I just added the plt.close() function. Thanks though.